# How to rename observations based upon frequency in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Within my dataframe, I'm trying to rename certain observations in column 'Name' based upon their respective frequency. That is, I want to rename the observations with a Name frequency lower than 100. If any name occurs less than 100 times in the dataset, I want to rename all those observations "Base" in the Name column. Here is an example:

```
Game   Home Runs     Name 

1          2        Hank Aaron
2          3        Babe Ruth
3          1        Ted Williams
3          4        Hank Aaron
4          2        Ted Williams
...
```

If Ted Williams's and Babe Ruth's names were to appear few than 100 times in the data frame, their names would be replaced with "Base" for all values of the Name column.

```
Game   Home Runs     Name 

1          2        Hank Aaron
2          3        Base
3          1        Base
3          4        Hank Aaron
4          2        Base
...
```

Additionally, I need the observations to be in the same dataframe, as I plan on running regressions using the new Name vector as an independent (individual effects) variable in a regression.

Apologies if I over-explained. Just a little lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `table` to count number of times each `Name` occurs in the dataframe, using `Filter` keep only those names which occur less than 100 times, match them in the original dataframe using `%in%` and replace.

```
df$Name[df$Name %in% names(Filter(I, table(df$Name) < 100))] <- 'Base'
```

Comment: Dumb question: what does "I" represent inside of the Fileter call?

Comment: In this case here `table(df$Name) < 100` returns a logical values of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values but we are interested only in `TRUE` values which we want to replace, using `I` in `Filter` we keep only `TRUE` values and remove the `FALSE` ones.

Comment: Thank you so much. I ran your code from before and it yields this warning message: Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, dat$Name %in% names(Filter(I, table(dat$Name) <  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated. It looks like the code worked for the most part, but the observations with frequency less than 100 were replaced by NAs, rather than being replaced by "Base." Any thoughts on why that might be/how to remedy it?

Comment: `Name` is of class `factor`. Run `df$Name <- as.character(df$Name)` first and then try the answer.

Comment: On first glance that appears to have worked. You are incredible, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(forcats)

df %>%

   mutate(Name = fct_lump(Name, n = 100, other_level = "Base"))
```